# Counting of different channels diverge and jumps

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, counting

I'm trying to realize a counting module. My basic setup:
FPGA (Digilent's Arty with Xilinx Artix-35T) with two BNC cables attached to IO ports connected to a signal generator and via USB/UART to the PC for reading out. My signal generator produces with, say, 1 Hz some TTL signal.

I now want to count the amount of events in channel 1, in channel 2 and the coincidences of channels 1 and 2. While the basic principle works, I see channels 1 and 2 separate, even though they have the same input (via BNC-T connector). Also, sometimes one of the output channels jumps - in either direction, see figure.
[image: counting]
The violet channel ("Channel 1") has a different slope than green ("Channel 2"). Also the coincidences make here two little lossy jumps.

My sequential counting code looks like

```
reg [15:0] coinciInt [(numCoincidences -1):0]; // internally store events
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)    // every time the clock rises...
begin
    signalDelay <= signal;                // delayed signal for not counting the same event twice

    if(reset)                             // reset
    begin
        for(i=0;i<numCoincidences;i=i+1) 
            coinciInt[i] <= 16'b0;
    end
    else                                  // No reset
    begin
        for(i=1;i<numCoincidences;i=i+1)   // loop through all coincidence possibilities:
        begin 
            if( ((signal & i) == i) && ((signalDelay & i) != i) )   // only if signal give coincidence, but did not give before, it's a coincidence
            begin                         // "(signal & i) == i" means that "signal" is checked if bitmask of "i" is contained: 
                                          // ((0011 & 0010) == 0010) is true, since 0011 & 0010 = 0010 == 0010  
                coinciInt[i] <= coinciInt[i] + 1'b1;    // the i-th coincidence triggered, store it
            end
        end
    end
end // end of always

assign coinci = coinciInt;  // the output variable is called coinci, so assign to this one
```

Please note that all events are in the register coinci - coincidences as well as 'single events'. Ideally, coinci[1] should store events of channel 1, coinci[2] these of channel 2 and coinci[3] coincidences between 1 and 2, since channels are labelled by 1,2,4,8,...,2^n and coincidences by the respective sum. coinci[0] is used for some kind of checksum, but that's off-topic now.

Are there any ideas for the missing counts? For the different slopes?

Thank you very much

**Edit 1**

@Brian Magnuson pointed to the meta stability issue. Using multi-buffered inputs solved the issue of diverging channels. That works nicely. Although I don't fully understand the reason for this, I also did not see any jumps in the coincidence channel so far. You probably save me a lot of time, thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.  Sorry for the short answer.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#Timing_considerations has a bit more info.  Basically without the synchronizer you are guaranteed to occasionally violate the setup/hold requirements of the first FFs that your inputs fan out to.  When this happens the state (0/1) that the flop goes to is not deterministic.  The synchronizer 'contains' that behavior and doesn't let it contaminate your counter logic.  Another google'able phrase would be 'clock domain crossing'.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect a meta-stability problem.  Your incoming pulses on ch1/ch2 are probably not synchronized with the system clock you are using. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metastability_in_electronics).

Because of this you are probably sometimes catching the counter updates 'mid-stride' so to speak which will cause unexpected behavior.

To fix this you can flop the inputs twice (called a dual-rank synchronizer) before feeding them into the rest of your logic.  Usually multi-bit synchronization requires a bit more careful handling but in your case each bit can be treated independently.